Can tables lose prime attributes during 2NF normalization?
I want to bring this table into a 2NF design:



Student-ID
Teacher-No
Teacher
StudentSkill




S1
1
Ott
Python


S1
2
Biegler
Python


S1
1
Ott
SQL


S1
2
Biegler
SQL


S2
1
Hansen
Python


S2
2
Muller
Python


S3
1
Smith
HTML


S3
1
Smith
Java



Student-ID uniquely identifies a student.
Teacher is the name of a teacher, depedent on the combination of Student-ID and Teacher-No.
StudentSkill is a skill a student possesses, completely unrelated to the teacher.
The table says:
Student S1 has two teachers (Ott, Biegler) and two unrelated skills (Python, SQL).
Student S2 has two teachers (Hansen, Muller) and one unrelated skill (Python).
Student S3 has one teacher (Smith) and two unrelated skills (HTML, Java).
The primary key is the combination of (Student-ID, Teacher-No, StudentSkill).
There is a partial dependency. Teacher is dependent only on Student-ID and Teacher-No. So I create a new table for the teacher names:



Student-ID
Teacher-No
Teacher




S1
1
Ott


S1
2
Biegler


S2
1
Hansen


S2
2
Muller


S3
1
Smith



and the original table loses the Teacher column:



Student-ID
Teacher-No
StudentSkill




S1
1
Python


S1
2
Python


S1
1
SQL


S1
2
SQL


S2
1
Python


S2
2
Python


S3
1
HTML


S3
1
Java



What about the column Teacher-No in the (Student-ID, Teacher-No, StudentSkill) table?
It does not do anything useful (since skills are unrelated to teachers), but it's part of the primary key, so I cannot touch it during creation of the 2NF.
Can tables lose prime attributes during 2NF normalization?

@Priyank if I encountered this problem during development I'd just drop the Teacher-No  column from the (Student-ID, Teacher-No, StudentSkill) table and afterwards any duplicate rows.

There is no need of Teacher No in second table. Each table can have Primary key as per the records in that table . There is no need to carry a column in another table just because of it is part of composite primary key in a different table.

What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [ask] [Help] PS What does "what about" mean? If you have a specific question re some expectation, give your full clear reasoning in small obviously correct steps & what you expect & why you expect that.  PS It doesn't matter if you notice something while following an algorithm. Just follow it. PS 2NF is not useful. 3NF is always possible preserving FDs. We don't go to higher NFs by going through lower NFs. Moreover that can preclude the best higher NFs from arising. PS Only certain partial FDs are problematic for 2NF.

Where are you 1st stuck following what published or justified appropriate process, having done what?

"Teacher is the name of a teacher, depedent on the combination of Student-ID and Teacher-No." Yes but from the table it is also not dependent on only one of them, but you haven't said that, and you may or may not think the quote includes that, but the natural language is ambiguous. Your use of natural language is unclear. Use technical terms & notation & use them correctly & give a closure or cover for all the relevant constraints. Also in real life we would expect that a teacher goes by the same name for every student so this is a poor real-world example for the given constraints.

Definitions of NFs are faqs. Normalizing to 3NF & hence 2NF is a faq. "My question is whether it satisfies 2NF" Not according to your post. "What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question?" PS Please clarify via edits, not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments.

@philipxy The task is to bring the original table into 2NF, not 3NF. The original table has 3 prime attributes (Student-ID, Teacher-No, StudentSkill). Teacher-No enumerates teachers for each student. In other words each student can have 1 to n teachers. After splitting the table as shown I end up with a useless column Teacher-No in the last table, which is technically still a prime attribute. My question is whether my solution satisfies 2NF regardless, or whether I HAVE to remove the prime attribute Teacher-No from the last table.

Again: "Please clarify via edits, not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments." "My question is [...]"--Again: "Not according to your post." "What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question?" "2NF, not 3NF"--Again: Putting into 3NF puts into 2NF. PS "does not do anything useful"--Unclear & what does it have to do with normalizing to 2NF?? "tables lose prime attributes"--What does "lose" mean? 1 table is normalized to other ones. "so I cannot touch it" Why?? What do any of these vague concerns have to do with 2NF? Please edit your post to ask 1 question & address all my comments.

The decomposition you proposed satisfies 2NF.
The (Student-ID, Teacher-No, Teacher) table (key attributes bold) is in 2NF because Teacher depends on both Student-ID and Teacher-No.
The (Student-ID, Teacher-No, StudentSkill) table is in 2NF because it has no non-key attributes.
However, this is not the only way to achieve 2NF in this scenario, and a better design would be to decompose the original table into the following tables.



Student-ID
Teacher-No
Teacher




S1
1
Ott


S1
2
Biegler


S2
1
Hansen


S2
2
Muller


S3
1
Smith






Student-ID
StudentSkill




S1
Python


S1
SQL


S2
Python


S3
HTML


S3
Java



This design removes the redundant Teacher-No column from the table with the skills and also satisfies 2NF.
So to answer your original question whether during 2NF normalization tables can lose prime attributes: Yes, but they don't have to. In this concrete scenario, the design that removes the prime-attribute Teacher-No from the skill table is the better one.
Interestingly, even going to 3NF would not force the removal of the redundancies in your proposed decomposition, because 3NF it is not concerned with dependencies between attributes that are part of the primary key. BCNF however would catch it.

"BCNF however would catch it." No. That "bad" design is already in BCNF. The "bad" table satisfies no non-trivial FDs. Its further anomalies are from MVDs. It isn't in 4NF, which the "good" design is.

"is in 2NF because Teacher depends on both Student-ID and Teacher-No" That is typical unclear ambiguous language. It's because it isn't dependent on a set of less than both while being dependent on the set of both.

For 2NF

Table must be in 1NF
There should be no partial dependency of a non key column on composite Primary key.

So in this case it is correct to remove column Teacher No in second table since skill is only dependent on student id.

Skill is a key column, so why does it matter what it depends on?
